# Pandas .apply() subfunction is changing main dataframe

Tags: python, group-by, pandas, data-mining

Pandas/Python users,

I'm trying to analyze x and y coordinate data but in groups. 
For some reason when I pull out the values of a column into a series to analyze them one by one and then try to return the full dataframe, some columns get dropped off.
I'm not sure why my main dataframe is being modified when I'm not making any modifications.

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


def eventDetector(x):
    x_arr = pd.Series(x['X_COOR'].values.copy())
    y_arr = pd.Series(x['Y_COOR'].values.copy())
    print('For x returned: %s for y: %s' % (x_arr.values, y_arr.values))
    for x, y in zip(x_arr, y_arr):
        1+1
        print('Here are the x: %s and y: %s' % (x, y))
    return x


prev_x = 0
prev_y = 0

df = pd.read_csv('/users/aleksarias/desktop/SubS.csv')
df.sort(['WA', 'MRG', 'DATETIME'], inplace=True)
dfg = df.groupby(['WA', 'MRG'])
print(dfg.head(1))
dfa = dfg.apply(eventDetector)
print(dfa.head())
```

Input:

```
              WA    LEV        DATETIME    MRG    X_COOR    Y_COOR
WA MRG                                                            
4  10_10 714   4  6317C   11/8/13 17:24  10_10 -25901000 -33021000
   10_12 716   4  9295T  11/25/13 10:46  10_12 -27604000 -21857000
   10_13 720   4  2965S   10/14/13 1:56  10_13 -27887187 -12670910
   10_14 722   4  6025P    11/4/13 9:26  10_14 -25534000  -7426000
   10_15 726   4  6817C  11/13/13 10:09  10_15 -30274000   -397000
   10_16 730   4  6025P    11/4/13 9:26  10_16 -25265000   4181000
   10_17 733   4  4865S  10/27/13 15:56  10_17 -28157000  10448000
   10_18 735   4  4975C   10/29/13 5:22  10_18 -28182842  10506772
   10_19 736   4  5906C   11/3/13 11:36  10_19 -26065098  19681040
   10_21 738   4  6025P    11/4/13 9:26  10_21 -25388000  34586000
   10_23 742   4  4865S  10/27/13 15:56  10_23 -27075000  42340000
   10_24 746   4  4975C   10/29/13 5:22  10_24 -27812334  44613674
   10_25 748   4  4865S  10/27/13 15:56  10_25 -25996000  53117000
```

Output (print(dfa.head())):

```
WA  MRG  
4   10_10   -25901000
    10_12   -27604000
    10_13   -29411000
    10_14   -25423000
    10_15   -25740000
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def eventDetector(x):                                    # 1
    x_arr = pd.Series(x['X_COOR'].values.copy())
    y_arr = pd.Series(x['Y_COOR'].values.copy())
    print('For x returned: %s for y: %s' % (x_arr.values, y_arr.values))
    for x, y in zip(x_arr, y_arr):                       # 2
        1+1
        print('Here are the x: %s and y: %s' % (x, y))
    return x                                             # 3
```

1. Here, `x` is a DataFrame.
2. Now, `x` is reassigned to a value in `x_arr`.
3. The value returned is the current value of `x`, which is the last
   value in `x_arr`, not the original DataFrame.